# prompt for Windows global group

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to prompt for Windows user names and Window global group names in my application (C++).

If you right-click a file or directory in Windows Explorer, choose properties, go to the Security tab, click the Edit button and then the Add button, you get a standard screen to select (and validate) user and group names.

Is there any way to invoke this screen using the Windows API?

Comment: Welp, you can probably try to hack your way into `rshx32.dll` which displays this dialog and use its COM interface but there's no info available so you'll have to use [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) to reverse-engineer it with the obvious legal restrictions on using it publicly, besides it's kinda reckless to rely on a nonpublished API.